# Как программно задать через какую сетевую карту делать отправку пакетов

Tags: c++, ethernet

Имеется 2 порта Ethernet на материнской плате. К обоим портам подключена одна и та же локальная сеть — разные IP (`192.168.0.101` и `192.168.0.102`). Предполагается имитировать 2 физических устройства на одном ПК.

Задача в том, чтобы из программы на C++ часть инфы выдавалось через `...101` IP, а другая через `...102`. Подскажите как это реализовать, куда смотреть? Если есть примерчик вообще замечательно.

Comment: Разные bind() к разным сокетам, с последующими раздельными connect() или accept() в зависимости от того, клиент вы пишете или сервер. Заметьте, я истолковываю отсутствие OS-specific тэгов как "мне для какой угодно ОС", а не "существует лишь Та Самая ОС".

Comment: Не думаю, что это правильная реализация. Если вам нужно имитировать два устройства, то ставьте виртуальную машину и в неё прокидывайте сетевую карту.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вам нужно уточнить, с какого именно адреса (и или порта) должно "исходить подключение", используйте функцию bind перед вызовом connect. Это выглядит странно (обычно bind используется для серверной части).

Так как не указана ось, то я скопипастил код с [msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-bind), оно там плюс-минус одинаково.

```
service.sin_family = AF_INET; // очевидно
service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.101"); // адрес
service.sin_port = htons(27015); // если нужен и порт специальный
service.sin_port = 0; // оставить порт на откуп системы 
//----------------------
// а дальше по классике
iResult = bind(ListenSocket, (SOCKADDR *) &service, sizeof (service));
```